# How to have multiple views of the same buffer in vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have been trying to implement a function in vimscript to switch between two views of the same buffer. The functionality I want to have is like this:
I press a key and the screen position and cursor are moved to my previously saved location. If there is not yet another saved location, it creates one at the current view and cursor location. I have a vimscript function that does exactly this functionality i described:

```
fun! SwitchFileMarker(reset)

    if a:reset == 1
        if exists("b:switch_file_window")
            unlet b:switch_file_window
        endif
    endif

    if exists("b:switch_file_window")
        let cursor_location = getpos("'0")
        let top_location = getpos("'9")
        :execute "normal! m0Hm9`0"
        call setpos('.', top_location)
        :execute "normal! zt"
        call setpos('.', cursor_location)
        :execute "normal! zv"
    else
        " save the location
        :execute "normal! m0Hm9`0"
    endif

    let b:switch_file_window = 1
endfun

nmap <leader>b :call SwitchFileMarker(0)<CR>
nmap <leader>B :call SwitchFileMarker(1)<CR>
```

The only problem with this function is I want it to save the folds of the current view and load the folds of the saved view when the function is called. I can achieve this by using :mkview and :loadview, but the problem with that is if the number of lines in the file changes, the folds are lost. The :mkview function seems to remember the folds at a specific line number, and If ive added several lines above that fold location while editing the file, when i use :loadview, the fold is lost. using the marks, as done in the function i show works to save my cursor position (but not folds) because the marks keep track of the changing line number. The funcionality that I am trying to get is essentially like having two views of a buffer but in the same window, rather than two windows. If i have a two windows editing the same buffer, I can add lines in one window and the folds are not lost in the other, so this is exactly the functionality I want, just in one window instead of two. Any suggestions how this can be done?

Comment: `I have been trying to implement a function in vimscript to switch between two views of the same buffer.` Any good reason against simply opening two split windows? `I want it to save the folds of the current view and load the folds of the saved view when the function is called` So you're using manually created folds? Any reason not to use any kind of automatic folds?

Comment: The reason I dont want to use the two split windows is just for saving screen space.  Having two split windows, and switching the size of them so one is very small, and then alternating which takes the whole vertical size of the screen is the exact functionality I am trying to implement. The reason i dont want to use this solution is the wasted screen space (even at its smallest, the small window  takes 2 lines), and the jump list will be different between the windows. And the foldmethod is indent, not manual, but they are still lost when some lines are added or removed.

Comment: 1) Two lines aren't worth the effort, IMO. Besides, you have tabs. 2) winsaveview() and winrestview() are much better here than fiddling with bookmarks. 3) Automatic folds (including fdm=indent) cannot get lost, as they are recalculated on the fly. You probably mean "open/close state is lost". Yes, mkview saves absolute line numbers with zo/zc, and, IMO, it is one of the reasons why it's totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

Use marks!

To set a mark, you can use `m<letter>` or `:mark <letter>`.

To go to a marked line, use `'<letter>`. To go to the exact position, prefer `` `<letter> ``.

If the letter is lowercase, it is buffer-local. If it is uppercase, it is global.

Edit: OP wants to save folds, which this can’t do. But it’s helpful to know anyway, so I’m leaving the answer.

Comment: I am already using marks in the vimscript function in the original post